# ASP.net Core 1.1.0 uploading file to azure storage - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, file-upload, azure-storage, asp.net-core-1.1

I imported a project from Visual Studio 2015 into Visual Studio 2017, I had an upload service that worked in 2015 that took a posted `IFormFile` and uploaded to a container in Azure Storage.

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<string> UploadFileToBlob(IFormFile file, string fileName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AppSettings.AzureStorageConnectionString);

        // Create a blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Get a reference to a container 
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(AppSettings.AzureStorageContainer);

        // If container doesn’t exist, create it.
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob, null, null);

        // Get a reference to a blob 
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        // Create or overwrite the blob with the contents of a local file
        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream()) // file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the line `using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())` that says:

> "Module 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' should be referenced"

I looked around to try to find that, tried to go to add a reference like I have in the past, and there isn't an option to even select COM objects?

Any idea what's up?

Comment: Have you installed package `Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http`?

Comment: I had not installed that package yet.  I just tried that and still getting the error re: System.Private.CoreLib

Comment: Are you using Resharper? Can you tell us the version of it?

Answer (score 0):

> "Module 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' should be referenced"

According to your mentioned that it indicates that System.Private.CoreLib is not loaded

Please have a try to add it with the following code in the **Startup.cs**:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var assemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(x).Location))
            .ToList();
            assemblies.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Private.Corelib")).Location));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i had the similar problem. By updating Resharper to the version 2017.2 EAP 3, it solved my problem. If you're also using Resharper, try to update it :

Download & install 2017.2 EAP 3
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/

My code to upload a file :

```
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
            {
                string filePath = "UploadedFiles/" + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                   await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                return Json("file uploaded successfully");
            }
```

file.OpenReadStream(); ==> is working also without error

For info : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464676#u=1494270865373